# how do I find out what php function from Wordpress is generating blocks of HTML using browser inspector?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress site, which I'm fairly new to. I'm not sure if this is a stupid question or not but I haven't been able to return any decent google results regarding this. Anyway, is there a way to find out what PHP function is generating a piece of HTML code using a browser code inspector like Chrome's? Thanks!

Comment: No, you cant. The browser just see's the generated html. Try a decent ide and do a full project text search. If you want a free one, netbeans is pretty good. If you are willing to spend a few quid, phpstorm is better

Answer (score 1):

No.

Once the data arrive to the browser, all the PHP code have been processed and you can't know what part of PHP generated which part of the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

No - not without modifying the php code to enable some kind of debugging. Chrome can only give you information about the received html document on the client side (you). But php code gets parsed server side.

Answer (score 0):

You kind of can:

- Download a copy of the theme and plugins folder
- Open the page on your site that you want to find the function for.
- Find a div/class that is specific to section e.g. `<article>`
- Open a text editor like notepad++ (one that will allow you to search through multiple files at ones)
- Use the find feature of chosen text editor and search for the div/class
- The result will show you a list of pages where that term is.
- Look through those pages for the function you are looking for (it might take a few goes)

The above it is a bit of a roundabout way of doing it, but I think other than looking through each file separately, it is you next best way.